# Bootstrap - Why: Row remove margin-left & not Row-fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

**Row :** `margin-left: -20px;`

**Row-fluid :** nothing about `margin-left`.

Why row-fluid is not removing this `margin-left` by a certain `%` ?

*Edit :*
`.row-fluid` > `.span` is adding `margin-left`.

Comment: Row-fluid don't have the property margin-left: -20px because it's using %. Ok - but still, what if you don't want those -20px in your following spans ?

Comment: I must use 'fuild' everywhere, i can't change the @gridGutterWidth.  but i need to get rid of it on ONE of my pages. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's hard to explain, your answer is in **bold**, the rest is context.

### What's the logic when in static layout?

The `span` elements have `margin-left: 20px` to stay separated from other `span`s.

The `row` element has `margin-left: -20px` to ensure that the first `span` -or any `span` placed at the "left column"- is placed at the begining of the `container`.

It works because the static `row` has not set its `width`, so that `margin-left: -20px` does not substract width to the element, that continues filling its ancestor.

### What happens in a fluid layout?

We could try the same logic, but the difference is that the `width` and `margin-left` of `span` elements is defined in percents, so **if we increase the actual width of the `row` element (by applying a negative `margin`), these `span` elements also increase its size, so they don't fit within the `container`.**

So fluid layout uses a different technique for achieving a similar result, just applies a `margin-left: 0` to the `:first-child`.

### Digging deeper

And why not use the same strategy in both layouts? Sure, that will simplify the implementation, but the static technique (that is not applicable to fluid) is more powerful. That's because any element that falls in the "left column", being `:first-child` or not, will became "margin-corrected". Static layouts need that kind of behaviour to comfortably providing responsiveness, fluid layouts can -more or less- manage without it.

Answer (score 4):

You can find out more about the fluid aspects of Bootstrap here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

It's because `<span>` tags ecapsulated within `.row` have a `margin-left: 20px`. The negative left margin is to counter this so that the row displays correctly. With the `.row-fluid > span` relationship, span tags within that encapsulation don't have a left margin therefore this doesn't need to be corrected within `.row-fluid`

Comment: What you say seems to be wrong, regarding to the documentation samples.

Comment: I looked at the code and CSS examples they provide, seemed like this was the case to me. Take a look at the CSS in bootstrap, regarding both .row and .row-fluid and their respective child spans.

Comment: Follow up question then:  Why is the margin-left 20px on the span to begin with that it needs to be counter acted?  Why not just remove the 20px margin from the span rather than counter act it with a -20px margin left on the row?